# Arrange the 26 letters of the alphabet in a row such that certain words do not occurr

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange the 26 letters of the alphabet in a row such that none of the following words are formed by consecutive letters in the arrangement INCH, LOST, or THIN?

The answer is: $26! - 3\times23! + 2\times20!$

I can't make sense of the answer. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ denote the arrangements with INCH in it, $L$ the arrangements
with LOST in it and $T$ the arrangements with THIN in it.

Denoting the number of arrangemens in e..g. $I$ by $n(I)$ we find with [inclusion/exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): $$n\left(I\cup L\cup T\right)=n\left(I\right)+n\left(L\right)+n\left(T\right)-n\left(I\cap L\right)-n\left(I\cap T\right)-n\left(L\cap T\right)+n\left(I\cap L\cap T\right)$$

This with:

- $n\left(I\right)=n\left(L\right)=n\left(T\right)=\left(1+22\right)!$
- $n\left(I\cap L\right)=\left(1+1+18\right)!$
- $n\left(L\cap T\right)=\left(1+19\right)!$
- $n\left(I\cap T\right)=n\left(I\cap L\cap T\right)=0$

Can you understand why?

If $A$ denotes all arrangements then $n(A)=26!$ and the answer is $n(A)-n\left(I\cup L\cup T\right)$